# Adding Material-UI Select with generated number range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a select with material-ui that give a range of number from 0 - 20,000,000 in 25,000 increments. I was able to achieve this with a for loop

```js
  for (let price = 0; price <= 20000000; price = price + 25000) {
    priceOptions.push({ id: price, title: `$${price.toLocaleString()}` });
  }
```

I feel like this is not the best way to go about it as it takes a 2-3 seconds when you click on the dropdown for to display the options.

If anyone has an idea of how to speed this up it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @aglasier I don't see a question, what are you trying to achieve? Are you asking how to get better performance out of your solution?

Comment: @AndrewLohr I can see now I probably didn't word that the best. Yes, I wanted to see if there was a better solution for this. It takes 2-3 seconds for the dropdown to display so was looking for away to speed this up.

Comment: You can integrate `Select` component with some virtualized library like `react-virtualized`. Personally, I'd use the `Autocomplete` component and tell the user to filter it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NearHuscarl [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69273867/adding-material-ui-select-with-generated-number-range/69285781#comment122451679_69273867):

> You can integrate `Select` component with some virtualized library
> like `react-virtualized`. Personally, I'd use the `Autocomplete`
> component and tell the user to filter it out.